# Processing mouse hovering

Tags: java, processing

I am new to processing and I am just trying to do some basci sketches to get familiar with it.
I have made a grid of circles and I would like to change a circle fill color when I hover on top of it.

```
color[] pastel = {#8dd3c7, #ffffb3, #bebada, #fb8072, #80b1d3, #fdb462, #7fc97f};
color[] palette = pastel;
int fc = palette[2];

int r = 40;
int s = 50;

void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
  smooth();
  noStroke();
  background(#e8e8e8);
//  background(#5e5e5d);
}

void draw() {
  for(int x = 0+s/2; x < width; x += s){
    for(int y = 0+s/2; y < height; y += s) {
      fill(fc);
      ellipse(x, y, r, r);
      
      if(dist(x, y, mouseX, mouseY) < r/2) {
    fc = palette[3];
  } else {
    fc = palette[2];
  }
}
  }

  }
```

Though, there is a shift between the mouse coordinates and the circle that change fill color - the one that change color is the one below the one I am hovering on.
Any idea why?
Thanks !

Comment: You change the colour after you've drawn the ellipse.

Comment: If I write: fill(fc) after the ellipse() function then the circle that change color is the one two circles below the one I am hovering on

Comment: By "change the colour" I mean "assign a new colour to `fc`.

Comment: I wrote the fill() and ellipse() commands at the end of the for loop and now it works. Thanks !

Comment: And hopefully you can see why :-)

Comment: well.. to be honest I do not fully understand why I had a consistent shift between the circle changing color and the hovering spot and the amount of that shift depends on where I place the fill() command

Comment: You check the mouse position for each circle. If you check and change the colour after you've already drawn the circle, the circle with the mouse hover gets the old colour (because you've already drawn it) and the next circle gets the new colour (because you draw it before you check the mouse hover again).

Answer (score 0):

We need to store the center of the circle. It seems like you have already done this. Then, use basic length formula. Here is a method I'd suggest you use.

```
boolean overCircle(int centerX, int centerY, int radius) {
    return sqrt(pow(mouseX - centerX, 2) + pow(mouseY - centerY, 2))
    <= radius;
}
```

It checks the length of a straight line from the mouse to the center of the circle, and if that length is more than the radius, obviously, it is no longer within the bounds of the circle.

If you plan on adding multiple of these types of circles, I'd recommend turning it into an object. Next, we need to be checking this method, so in draw,

```
if(overCircle(circleX, circleY, r) {
    circleColor = hoveringColor;
} else circleColor = notHoveringColor;
fill(circleColor);
circle(circleX, circleY);
```

Hope this helped. Have a good day.